# Can anyone help me figure out why my image map isn't working?

Tags: html, css, image, imagemap

The dimensions of the image itself are 447 x 447. I've tried different  formats and literally copying and pasting a post from Chegg but nothin is working.

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/447" alt="Ferris Family" usemap="#portait_map" />
  <figcaption>Kathleen Ferris and daughter Linda (1957)</figcaption>
</figure>

<map name="portrait_map">
  <area 
    shape="rect" 
    coords="10, 50, 192, 223" 
    href="tb_kathleen.html" 
    alt="Kathleen Ferris"
  />            
  <area shape="circle" coords="264, 108, 80" href="tb_linda.html" alt="Linda Ferris-White">
</map>
```

Comment: Typo: `portait_map`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/447" width="447" height="447" alt="Ferris Family" usemap="#portrait_map">
  <figcaption>Kathleen Ferris and daughter Linda (1957)</figcaption>
</figure>

<map name="portrait_map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="10,50,192,223" alt="Kathleen Ferris" href="tb_kathleen.html">
  <area shape="circle" coords="264,108,80" alt="Linda Ferris-White" href="tb_linda.html">
</map>
```

@xense was somehow right about giving `width` and `height` to the image element but its not necessary, you can try removing the `width` and `height` attributes and it should still work. Also there was a typo in your code.

Answer (score -2):

Try giving a width and height to the image and try again.

something like this:
width="400" height="379"
<area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" href={your url}>

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/447" alt="Ferris Family" usemap="#portait_map" width="447" height="447" />
  <figcaption>Kathleen Ferris and daughter Linda (1957)</figcaption>
</figure>

<map name="portrait_map">
  <area 
    shape="rect" 
    coords="10, 50, 192, 223" 
    href="tb_kathleen.html" 
    alt="Kathleen Ferris"
  />            
  <area shape="circle" coords="264, 108, 80" href="tb_linda.html" alt="Linda Ferris-White">
</map>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: I tried setting it to the base dimensions of the image but it still doesn't seem to have worked.